# Google Apps Script/Drive API appendParagraph values insert twice

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I needed a solution that copies into the current Doc the content of another set of Docs that are used as templates. (we need to retain the current docId). I wrote a simple Google Doc add-on that works like a charm... in some Google Apps domains.

I installed (and made screencasts) the IDENTICAL code in four different domains. In two of the domains the content copied from the selected "template" Doc gets (correctly) copied ONCE in the current Doc, however, in two other domains it gets injected TWICE!
All domains have identical settings (script run as admin, authorizations accepted, etc). I even installed a second copy in the faulty domains and that showed the same behaviour.

Anyone seen this behaviour?

```
function runInsert(template) {
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  if( targetDoc.getHeader() == null) {
    targetDoc.addHeader();
  }/
  if( targetDoc.getFooter() == null) {
    targetDoc.addFooter();
  }
  var templateDoc = DocumentApp.openById(template);
  // check for header, get elements and add to current doc
  var templateHeader = templateDoc.getHeader();
  if( templateHeader != null) {
    var totalElementsHeader = templateHeader.getNumChildren();
    for( var j = 0; j < totalElementsHeader; ++j ) {
      var header = targetDoc.getHeader();
      var element = templateHeader.getChild(j).copy();
      var type = element.getType();
      if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ){
        header.appendParagraph(element);
      }
    }
  }
  // check for body, get elements and add to current doc
  var templateBody = templateDoc.getBody();
  if( templateBody != null) { 
    var totalElementsBody = templateBody.getNumChildren();
    for( var j = 0; j < totalElementsBody; ++j ) {
      var body = targetDoc.getBody();
      var element = templateBody.getChild(j).copy();
      var type = element.getType();
      if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ){
        body.appendParagraph(element);
        Logger.log("j is " + j + " element contains " + element.getText());
      }
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE){
        body.appendTable(element);
      ....
    }
  }
  ... copy footer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found that the insert executed twice and fixed it in the sidebar javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Does the script run off of installed triggers? I had a similar issue with one of my scripts where I accidentally installed a trigger twice which was leading to the script running twice for every event.

Check your triggers and see if multiples are installed for your project in the script editor under **Resources > Current Project's Triggers**.

Comment: Nope, no triggers. Run from Test as add-on, or as published add-on, but in some domains it works correctly, in others the values are copied twice (2 domains OK, 2 domains NOK).

Comment: Have you verified whether the script is being called twice or whether it is only generating double output? (With Add-on's, and html output, you can't really effectively use the logger because it is asyncronus and resets every time a server-side dunction is called.)  It sounds like your script is being called twice. Are you able to provide any of your code?

Comment: I checked execution log and log and I see only one appendParagraph line for the body.